# Multiple Framebuffers in HTML5-Audio/Mozilla Audio Data API

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, html5-audio

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746841/how-to-do-panning-in-html5-audio-mozilla-audio-data-api/9993094#9993094) offered some nice insight on how to pan audio data using the [Mozilla Audio API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API). However I was wondering what can be done if I have multiple audio elements, and want a framebuffer for each? The code below stores a final mix of all audio elements together in the global variable 'data'.

```
var data; // global

for (ch=0; ch<channel_max; ch++)
{
    a1[ch].addEventListener('MozAudioAvailable', audioAvailable, false);
}

function audioAvailable(event) {
    // how to pass 'ch' such that 'data' is specific to its eventlistener?
    data = event.frameBuffer;
}
```

Is it possible to store an array buffer for each audio element separately? This may be as simple as restructuring how I call the eventlistener, but maybe not. At this point I'm not sure if the firefox API is capable of this but am curious to find out.

Comment: It's not clear to me what `a1` is here.  Is it a reference to an Audio element, or is it a Float32 array of samples?  In any event, [this section of the docs](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API#DOM_Implementation) says that `frameBuffer` contains the data for all channels interleaved.  If you know how many channels there are, you can use that information to sort the samples in `frameBuffer` into different arrays.

Comment: @JohnVinyard a1 is a reference to an audio element. By multiple channels I mean multiple audio elements. Sorry for not being more clear. All audio elements are in stereo, but there are several of them. Can you read a separate framebuffer for each audio element? Thanks, and I will edit the question for more clarity.